# typeorm geometry type Undefined type error

Tags: postgresql, graphql, nestjs, postgis, typeorm

everyone. I am creating a project that uses geometry data using postgresql postgis this time. So I want to declare geometry in the column and use it, but there's an error. Could you tell me why there is an error?

Multiple official documents were checked, but no method was found.
Commenting the coordinate column will create the code normally.

```
import {
    Column,
    CreateDateColumn,
    Entity,
    JoinColumn,
    ManyToOne,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn
} from 'typeorm';
import { Location_Group } from './location_group.entity';
import { Geometry } from 'geojson';
import { Field, ID, Int, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Location {
    @Field(() => ID)
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
    id: number;

    @Field(() => String)
    @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
    name: string;

    @Field()
    @Column({
        type: 'geometry',
        nullable: true,
        spatialFeatureType: 'Point',
        srid: 4326
    })
    coordinate: Geometry;

    @Field(() => Int)
    @Column({ type: 'int' })
    order_number: number;

    @Field()
    @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamptz' })
    created_at: Date;

    @Field(() => Location_Group)
    @ManyToOne(
        () => Location_Group,
        (location_group) => location_group.location
    )
    @JoinColumn([{ name: 'location_group_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' }])
    location_group: Location_Group;
}
```

[image]

Comment: as in error message - `Geometry` from geojson **is not a graphql type** (scalar/interface/object/list), can't be used in other grpahql defs like `@Field(type => Geometry)`

Comment: Could you tell me how to use geometry in typeOrm + graphql?

Comment: you didn't write about data shape you want to pass by graphql, point, list of points ? https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers

Comment: My problem was that I didn't make a scalar properly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: did you find a solution? can you post it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is someone who wants me to share the scalar I made, so I write it here. I hope this code helps you.

```js
import { GraphQLScalarType } from 'graphql';

export const GeoJSONPoint = new GraphQLScalarType({
    name: 'GeoJSONPoint',
    description: 'Geometry scalar type',
    parseValue(value) {
        return value;
    },

    serialize(value) {
        return value;
    },

    parseLiteral(ast) {
        const geometryData = {
            type: '',
            coordinates: []
        };

        for (const i in ast['fields']) {
            if (ast['fields'][i]['name']['value'] == 'type') {
                if (ast['fields'][i]['value']['value'] != 'point') {
                    return null;
                }
                geometryData.type = ast['fields'][i]['value']['value'];
            }

            if (ast['fields'][i]['name']['value'] == 'coordinate') {
                for (const j in ast['fields'][i]['value']['values']) {
                    geometryData.coordinates.push(
                        parseFloat(
                            ast['fields'][i]['value']['values'][j]['value']
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return geometryData;
    }
});
```